# addClass in Twig with if statement in item-list.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I try conditionally add a CSS class to a `<li>` element in `item-list.html.twig`.

```
{%- for item in items -%}

    {# check if is facet li #}
    {% if item.attributes.hasClass('facet-item') %}
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('list-group-item') }}>{{ item.value }}</li>
    {% endif %} 

{%- endfor -%
```

When I add the if statement like above, I don't get any output at all. If I remove the if statement I get correct output like:

```
<div class="item-list">           
    <ul data-drupal-facet-id="contactvoorkeur" class="js-facets-checkbox-links list-group">
        <li class="facet-item broodjeaap list-group-item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="facets-checkbox" id="contactvoorkeur-email" data-facetsredir="/search-person/cards?f[0]=contactvoorkeur%3Aemail">
            <label for="contactvoorkeur-email">E-mail <span class="facet-count">(2)</span></label>
            <a href="/search-person/cards?f[0]=contactvoorkeur%3Aemail" rel="nofollow" data-drupal-facet-item-id="contactvoorkeur-email" style="display: none;">E-mail <span class="facet-count">(2)</span>
            </a>
        </li>          
    <li class="facet-item broodjeaap list-group-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="facets-checkbox" id="contactvoorkeur-post" data-facetsredir="/search-person/cards?f[0]=contactvoorkeur%3Apost">
        <label for="contactvoorkeur-post">Post <span class="facet-count">(1)</span></label>
        <a href="/search-person/cards?f[0]=contactvoorkeur%3Apost" rel="nofollow" data-drupal-facet-item-id="contactvoorkeur-post" style="display: none;">Post <span class="facet-count">(1)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What does _does not work_ mean? Are you getting a wrong output or nothing at all?

Comment: Yes I get nothing at all. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me the problem might be with the if statement. Can you debug and make sure you enter the if block at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong here, as we do know know what problem you are having...

But `{{ item.attributes.addClass('list-group-item') }}` will add the `list-group-item` class to the `item`-element. (It does not print this class.)

Because of the surrounding code: `{% if item.attributes.hasClass('facet-item') %} ... {% endif %}`, I feel you want to add a class to the childs of `item`, not to `item` itself.

Why not output this instead?

```
<li class="list-group-item">{{item.value}}</li>
```

So the condition becomes:

```
{% if item.attributes.hasClass('facet-item') %}
  <li class="list-group-item">{{item.value}}</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You should put that inside the if statement you already have. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it's not working..?

Comment: Please define _not working_...

Comment: Sorry, I found out I was still adding another CSS class with a preprocess function for testing. If I remove this it's working. So also `<li{{ item.attributes.addClass('list-group-item') }}>{{ item.value }}</li>` works!